# How do I decode base64 encoded lines in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, base64, decode

I am trying to read a file & extract only the base64 encoded part. I am doing so by using sed to find the lines between the pattern's 'base64' & '--'.

I am able to do so using

```html
 sed -e '1,/base64/d' -e '/--/,$d' file.txt | sed '/^\s*$/d'
```

But when i try to decode it using base64 as shown below,

```
 sed -e '1,/base64/d' -e '/--/,$d' file.txt | sed '/^\s*$/d' | base64 -d
```

I get an error message as :-

```html
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:Microsoft Exchangbase64: invalid input
```

Please let me know what am i doing wrong and is there an alternate, better way to achieve the end result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ok..i dont get it why the question is getting downvoted. Actually i dont really care. But it would be really appreciated if someone could at leaset comment some helpful tip. Also, Sorry for bad english

Comment: Upvoted, because it was a downvote without explaining why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. the lines in the files were as follows

```html
QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSDQpNRVRIT0Q6UkVRVUVTVA0KUFJPRElEOk1pY3Jvc29mdCBFeGNoYW5nZSBTZ
XJ2ZXIgMjAxMA0KVkVSU0lPTjoyLjANCkJFR0lOOlZUSU1FWk9ORQ0KVFpJRDpBVVMgRWFzdGVybiBTdG
```

There was an end line character at the end, so all i had to do was remove it. Hence, now my code looks as below & it works :-

```html
sed -e '1,/base64/d' -e '/--/,$d' _12829640_21.12.-.5p.meeting.room_1485234639532_1.mail | sed '/^\s$/d' | tr -d "\n\r"  | base64 -d
```